# Best Kotlin builder implementation ever?

Tags: kotlin

I work with a lot's of generated kotlin data classes (openapi-generated) with val's and two common fields available and processed. So i can assign values only on construction, like:

```
data class StringRepresentation {
    val value: String,
    val available: Boolean,
    val processed: Boolean,
}

data class DoubleRepresentation {
    val value: Double,
    val available: Boolean,
    val processed: Boolean,
}
```

And i have to init lot's of them with common robust code, like:

```
val currentRepresentation = StringRepresentation("Something", true, false)
```

Can any pattern or Kotlin language support be used to remove robost object initialization?
It could be wonderful to use some kind of generic template method, something like this:

```
private inline fun  <reified T: StringRepresentation> buildRepresentation(
        value: Any,
        available: Boolean,
        processed: Boolean
    ): T {
    return when(T) {
        is StringRepresentation -> StringRepresentation(value.toString(), available, processed)
        else -> ...
    }
}
```

, but my types and properties are final and also syntax doesn't allow to set multiple generic boundaries. I can't figure it out the right approach for this. I guess in that case I need to write a builder, but this seems to be java way.

Is there any kotlin way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. In the sample code you give, it looks like you're just going to call buildRepresentation instead of the StringRepresentation constructor. Why would that be better? Would buildRepresentation return other objects (like DoubleRepresentation) too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that it is possible with your setup to write a builder that would actually be useful. Your `*Representation` data types stand in no explicit type relation to their respective type parameter (e.g. a `StringRepresentation` is not `Something<String>`), so what should be the return type of a generic builder function? It could only be `Any` and you would need to cast every result to its expected type in order to use it.

What you can do is to define a generic data class:

```
data class Representation<T>(
    val value: T,
    val available: Boolean,
    val processed: Boolean,
)
```

I know, you cannot use that class as super class of your specific data classes, but you can write extension functions that convert the generic representation for one value type into its corresponding specific representation:

```
fun Representation<String>.typed() = StringRepresentation(value, available, processed)
fun Representation<Double>.typed() = DoubleRepresentation(value, available, processed)
```

Then you can use the same code to create a data object of any type:

```
val stringRepresentation: StringRepresentation = Representation("x", false, true).typed()
val doubleRepresentation: DoubleRepresentation = Representation(1.0, false, true).typed()
```

---

But please note that **this is still not a generic solution** since whatever you put into the constructor `Representation` has to be typed explicitly as a `String` or `Double`, respectively.

Let's say you define a generic function for all undefined value types:

```
fun <T: Any> Representation<T>.typed(): Any = error("no typed representation for value type ${value::class}")
```

The specific cases above will still work, and you could additionally write something like this:

```
val x : Any = 2.0
val someRep: Any = Representation(x, true, false).typed()
```

This is syntactically correct and will compile, but it will not work as desired, because what you get is an IllegalArgumentException ("no typed representation for value type class kotlin.Double"), because `x` is not typed as `Double`, but as `Any`.

Comment: Interesting approach, thx.